# How to use relation using attach method in laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

```
users

id int(10)
name varchar(255)
p_id int(10)

some_record
id int(10)
text varchar(35)


record_relation
some_record_id int(10)
user_id int (10)
or_id int(10)
dr_id int(10)
```

Relationship using attach method to be clear wanted their store some_record data inside record_relation. How this is possible please guide

Inside some_record model

```
public function RecordRelation() {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\Record', 'pivot_table');
    }
```

Comment: You should probably consider renaming your entities - it's really hard to even understand the question so far ... could you please post both models code and a db schema image?

Answer (score 0):

Check out this documentation pages: [Working with Pivot tables](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#working-with-pivot-tables) and [Inserting related models](https://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#inserting-related-models)

**To save data in pivot table:**

From documentation:

```
$user->roles()->attach($id, ['expires' => $expires]);
```

Which in your case would become something like the following:

```
$user->pivot_table()->attach($some_record_id, ['or_id' => 123, 'dr_id' => 456]);
```

**To update pivot:**

From documentation:

```
User::find(1)->roles()->updateExistingPivot($roleId, $attributes);
```

Which in your case would become something like the following:

```
$user->pivot_table()->updateExistingPivot($some_record_id, ['or_id' => 888, 'dr_id' => 999]);
```

Hope that helps.